# How can I assign variables from file into a bash script and write a specific loop for it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a file containing n lines and each line has three variables(i.e. words) separated by a comma. I want to write a script in bash which takes each variable and fill a template message such as:

```
To $variable1 
You need to buy $variable2
From $variable3
```

My problem is I don't know how to assign these variables in bash, and how to make a bash script that will generate the message above in a different file names for all the n lines.

Comment: assigning variables in bash is as simple as `poop=35` ... you can do that right on the command line and then `echo $poop` to view the value... Look into **awk** and look into **for loops** to parse your file into variables in your script...  you can use redirection ">" to create files with the variable names you parsed. `echo "hello" > $poop.txt`... there are plenty of tutorials everywhere on the web on all of these.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a.file` contains your data:

```
while IFS=, read var1 var2 var3; do
    msg="""\
To $var1 
You need to buy $var2
From $var3
"""
    echo "$msg"
done < a.file
```

`$IFS` is the character that separates your words

`read` is a builtin shell function that reads a line of input, split it into words and assigns them to the given variables.